# How can I make a symmetric tridiagonal matrix (Wilkinson matrix) in R and compute the eigenvalues?

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, eigenvector

> In linear algebra, Wilkinson matrices are symmetric, tridiagonal,
> order-N matrices with pairs of nearly, but not exactly, equal
> eigenvalues. Wilkinson matrices have applications in many fields, including scientific computing, numerical linear algebra, and signal processing.([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson_matrix))

Following the matrix example from wikipedia, I have this matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    3    1    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    2    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    1    1    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    0
[6,]    0    0    0    0    1    2    1
[7,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    3
```

How can I create this matrix and compute the eigenvalues in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this script you can create a Wilkinson matrix and compute the eigen values

```
identity_6_by_7 <- diag(rep.int(1, 6), 6, 7) # create a 6x7 matrix with ones on the main diagonal
below_the_diagonal <- rbind(0, identity_6_by_7) # create a row of zeros below the diagonal 
identity_7_by_6 <- diag(rep.int(1, 6), 7, 6) # matrix with the ones offset one up from the diagonal
above_the_diagonal <- cbind(0, identity_7_by_6) # create a row of zeros above the diagonal 
on_the_diagonal <- diag(abs(seq.int(-3, 3))) # diagonal of values from abs(-3 to 3)
wilkinson_21 <- below_the_diagonal + above_the_diagonal + on_the_diagonal
eigen(wilkinson_21)$values # eigen values
```

You can check the eigen:

```
eigen(wilkinson_21)$values
[1]  3.7615572  3.7320508  2.3633282  2.0000000  1.0000000  0.2679492 -1.1248854
```